# Not triggered catch from action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have action that always returns Promise.reject:

```
module.exports = { create: createActionAsync('CREATE_USER', () => {
    return Promise.reject({
        response: {
            type: 'error',
            message: 'It will be implemented soon',
        },
    });
})}
```

But in component catch block doesn't work:

```
onAddUser(data) {
    const { userActions: { create } = {} } = this.props;

    create(data)
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(err => console.error(err)) // not working
```

Comment: What does `createActionAsync` do? It doesn't look like `create` necessarily returns a promise.

Comment: @AlanFriedman is a method from 'redux-act-async' library. It dispatch 3 types of actions (request, ok, error) depending on the result of the promise